# Error getting row of data from DataTable when searching

Tags: javascript, razor, datatable

I'm having trouble getting the following code to work. I have a table and wish to search the table for some data and return the row of data/array with the matching string (field13a). When running the code I get the following error:

```
outputReferenceError: filteredData is not defined
```

I have no idea what "filteredData" is

Code:

```
var field13a = field13.substring(0, 4); 
var indexes = locTable
    .rows()
    .indexes()
    .filter(function (value, index) {
        return field13a === locTable.row(value).data()[0];
    });

console.log(locTable.rows(indexes).data().toArray());
```

Not sure where I am going wrong, I have looked on Internet but not had any luck finding the best way to fix this or a better solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the error was but ended up using this:

```
var names = locTable
    .rows(function ( idx, data, node ) {
        return data[1] === field13a ?true:false;
    } )
    .data();
console.log(names[0]);
```